# Xcode: Split code in multiple files

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using a new class with nib and tableview. To costumize the TableViewCells i have defined some functions and constant values (#define) and special TableViewCells

```
 - (UITableViewCell*) CreateMultilinesCell :(NSString*)cellIdentifier { ... }
```

I want to use this costumized cell in other TableViews too.
Is it possible to pack this specific code into a file and load it into multiple files ?
like *inlcude* in PHP

*From comment: What is the most reduced (OO-free, just functions) file possible in iPhone SDK ?*

i hope you understand what i mean.
cheers Simon

Comment: (Note: this question has absolutely /nothing/ to do with Xcode, but it has to do with the iPhone SDK, so you might want to clarify that in the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and put it in it's own file, and create a header and include that and call that function.

Like this:

- CellCreator.m: `UITableViewCell *CreateMultilinesCell(NSString *cellIdentifier) { ... }`
- CellCreator.h (and be sure to `#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>`): `UITableViewCell *CreateMultilinesCell(NSString *cellIdentifier);`
- Your TableView files (at the top): `#include "CellCreator.h"`
- To use it: `UITableViewCell *cell = CreateMultilinesCell(@"identifier);`

Comment: As far as I tried do I have to create a NSObject, but my goal was to use a bunch of standartfunctions without creating a new instance of my class. Is my desire against OOP ?
Simon

Comment: You don't have to make a class for everything. OOP isn't always the right solution...

Comment: but i'm getting errors with no @interface.

What is the most reduced (OO-free, just functions) file possible in iPhone SDK ?
Sorry, but I'm really struggling with this.

Comment: Just create it as you would in C. Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so just create is as a standard .c file (but named .m, of course).